# JBoss AS 7 remote standalone client auth

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x, jaas

I have a some ear deployed on JBoss AS7 with
jboss-app.xml

```
<jboss-app xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       version="7.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee ">
<security-domain>FooDomain</security-domain>
```

In standalone.xml I have

```
<security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
   <authentication>
       <jaas name="FooDomain"/>
   </authentication>
</security-realm>
...
<security-domain name="FooDomain" cache-type="default">
<authentication>
    <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
    </login-module>
    <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/MyDS"/>
        <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from users where user_id=?"/>
        <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role, 'Roles' from roles where user_id=?"/>
        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
    </login-module>
</authentication>
</security-domain>
```

I can make a lookup some ejb from standalone client and authentication is successful when I use code like this:

```
final Hashtable<Object, Object> p = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();
p.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
p.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
p.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
p.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://10.10.1.18:4447");
p.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");
p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.class.getName());
context = new InitialContext(p);
```

The problem is that if I provide wrong credentials, I see in debug console

```
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed
```

but I can't catch it.

Server logs (not important parts cutted):

```
TRACE [DatabaseServerLoginModule] initialize
TRACE [DatabaseServerLoginModule] Security domain: FooDomain
TRACE [DatabaseServerLoginModule] DatabaseServerLoginModule, dsJndiName=java:/MyDS
TRACE [DatabaseServerLoginModule] principalsQuery=select password from users where user_id=?
TRACE [DatabaseServerLoginModule] rolesQuery=select role, 'Roles' from roles where user_id=?
TRACE [DatabaseServerLoginModule] suspendResume=true
TRACE [DatabaseServerLoginModule] login
TRACE [DatabaseServerLoginModule] suspendAnyTransaction
TRACE [DatabaseServerLoginModule] Excuting query: select password from users where user_id=?, with username: test
TRACE [DatabaseServerLoginModule] Obtained user password
TRACE [DatabaseServerLoginModule] resumeAnyTransaction
DEBUG [DatabaseServerLoginModule] Bad password for username=test
TRACE [DatabaseServerLoginModule] abort
```

When I try to use LoginContext just nothing happens on server.
Configuration

```
public class DefaultJassConfiguration extends Configuration {
@Override
public AppConfigurationEntry[] getAppConfigurationEntry(String name) {
    Map options = new HashMap();
    options.put("debug", true);
    AppConfigurationEntry[] entries = {
            new AppConfigurationEntry("org.jboss.security.ClientLoginModule", AppConfigurationEntry.LoginModuleControlFlag.REQUIRED, options)
    };
    return entries;
}
}
```

Test

```
Configuration.setConfiguration(new DefaultJassConfiguration());
try {
        LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("FooDomain", new UsernamePasswordHandler("test", "test".toCharArray()));
        lc.login();
        System.out.println(lc.getSubject());
    } catch (LoginException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Perhaps LoginContext don't know server address? I try to add

```
System.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "remote://10.10.1.18:4447");
```

but with no effect.

How to make LoginContext work? Or how to catch SaslException?
I consider to make some dummy bean with method always returned true and call it after login, but it looks ugly.

P.S. I'm sorry for my English (It makes me a bit shy)

Comment: You want to catch the exception on the client right?

Comment: You could try to extend the security module class and wrap the security check code in a try/catch. In case you would get an exception to throw it back to the client. I just hope it's not further up that the Exception is suppressed.

Comment: With security module class I meant DatabaseServerLoginModule

Comment: Thanks, but I'm wondering why LoginContext doesn't work. It is deprecated for JBossAS 7?

Comment: Did you find an answer regarding the LoginContext ? I'm trying to migrate similar code from JBoss 5 to JBoss 7. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately nope. This is the only reason for using older version of JBoss for me. :(

Answer (score 0):

ClientLoginModule is not currently supported on AS7 - all that login module does is associate the username and password with a thread local it does not perform any real authentication.

Regarding the InitialContext you should be seeing an exception thrown when you try and use it.